# My field name is Arabic and didn't work

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, arabic

I'm working on a database in access and I need to insert data into a table from a form when a button is clicked. Here is my code, but it didn't work.

Is the problem with my fields' names as it is Arabic?

```
Dim strInsert As String
Dim db As DAO.Database


strInsert = "INSERT INTO ÇáÍÖæÑ æ ÇáÇäÕÑÇÝ  [(ÑÞã ÇáãáÝ  )] values ('" & fileNO.Value & "');"

Debug.Print strInsert

db.Execute strInsert

Set db = Nothing
```

note: the undefined characters is the Arabic name

Comment: It is likely that the codification of the Access internal environment is diffferent that the script tool. Also it is possible that the database was created with a different codification than the currentone. So, I suggest you to change the current codification until you get the right one.

Comment: how could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is no probleme with arabic, you've just to use utf-8 encoding when you create the Database.

```
CREATE DATABASE "myDataBase"
ENCODING = 'UTF8';
```

I've tried an insert request and it's work :

```
INSERT INTO test(id, data) VALUES (8888, 'أحمد');
```

Comment: my table and field names are Arabic not the data included .... also I'm working on microsoft access not a sql server .... and this sql statement I write it in a VBA code

Comment: there is no problem, you have just to put the name of table between Quotation marks => "قاعدة"

Comment: Perhaps, this is a collation problem. Use this command : ALTER DATABASE (Database name here) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS ;
src : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929080.aspx

Comment: I try to convert it to english but also it didn't work ... here my code in english
'
Dim strInsert As String
Dim db As DAO.Database

strInsert = "INSERT INTO Attendence (File ID) values ('" & FileID.Value & "');"

Debug.Print strInsert

db.Execute strInsert

Set db = Nothing'

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to rename your field name temporarily to an English name (Latin letters).

Please avoid using non-Latin names in field names.

Comment: Based on my own experience, No. I have always avoided that. Try to display the labels(captions) in Arabic, so in the presentation layer instead of Database layer. 

You can use the "Caption" property of column to be able to display the caption in Arabic while the field name still Latin 
Check this screenshot to know what I exactly mean: 
http://prntscr.com/dapc8e

Comment: now I have a problem within my query ... I add a parameter but my data contains - "dash" so give me nothing ... any help ?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Code snippet or a screenshot?